# How to get notified when an Item is added to a ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems collection

Tags: c#, winforms, events, toolstrip

I am developing a MDI application in c#. I am having trouble when two MenuStrip are combined:

I have the parent Parent `Form` with its `MenuStrip parentMenu` and some `ToolStripMenuItem` elements:  `Option1`, `Option2`.

Then I have a child `Form` with its `MenuStrip parentMenu` and two `ToolStripMenuItem` elements: `Option1` and `OtherOption`. The merging propierties of these are match-only for `Opcion1`and append for `OtherOption`

Now, here is the problem: When the child form is showed and the two `MenuStrip`are combined, the event parentMenu.ItemAdded is tiggrered because `OtherOption`is added to the `parentMenu.Items` collection. This is not the case for `Option1`. Notice that there may be some elements in `Option1.DropDownItems`(in the child form) that are not present in the  `Option1.DropDownItems` in the parent form.

How can I get notified about these items that being added?

(Just for clarity: Suppose that `parentMenu.Items` only contains a `ToolStripMenuItem Option1` which only contains a `ToolStripMenuItem`, say 'optionA'. Suppose that `childMenu.Items` only contains a `ToolStripMenuItem Option1` which only contains `ToolStripMenuItem optionB`. When the two menus merge, how can I get notified about the item optionB being added the the father? Or how can I get notified about two menus merging, knowing which elements are new?).

Comment: Is there any reasons why I am not getting any answers? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MenuStrip merging moves menu items from one ToolStrip to another rather than cloning them, as was the case with MainMenu." See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404319%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Because it is moving them rather than cloning them, try the [`OwnerChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.ownerchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event on the `ToolStripItem`. Hook up to this event for each of your items and it will notify you when it is moved to another toolstrip.

Comment: Can the OnwerChanged event be tiggered if no merge is done (for any other reason) ?

Comment: Yes. If the owner changes, the event will fire. For example you could move it around manually. But this is not a problem because you can just look at the new owner and determine if it was merged or not (i.e. if the owner is the mdiparent's menustrip, you know it was merged).

Comment: Still feels like not the right way to do it. I'll mark it as valid if it is the only way

Comment: I know what you want...you want a MenuMerged event that would give you the list of items that were merged. Unfortunately it doesn't exist. I think the way I mentioned is the simplest way to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I though it auto assigned when marking answer as valid. There you go